# Fill in unfilled properties with other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an ActiveRecord model `@new_profile` that has some, but not all of its properties filled in. I have another model `@default_profile` that has a bunch of values I want to copy over, but only if the properties from the first are not filled in. Is there a built in way to do this besides a block like...

```
@new_profile.name ||= @default_profile.name
@new_profile.address ||= @default_profile.address
# etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```
@new_profile.update_attributes!(@default_profile.attributes.merge(@new_profile.attributes))
```

The problem with this, is that if the attribute is in @new_profile, but it is nil, the merge might leave the value set as nil.  You might need to do the following.

```
new_profile_attrs = @new_profile.attributes.reject{ |key,value| !value }
@new_profile.update_attributes!(@default_profile.attributes.merge(new_profile_attrs))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
@new_profile.attributes = @new_profile.attributes.reverse_merge @default_profile.attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@new_profile.update_attributes(@default_profile.attributes.merge(@new_profile.attributes))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to copy ALL the attributes (except `id` of course):

```
@new_profile.attributes.each{|k,v| @new_profile[k] ||= @default_profile[k] if k != 'id'}
```

Things like `update_attributes` won't allow you to copy `attr_protected`-attributes. **This thing should**.